# How to run tests on Chrome and Firefox browser via UFT?

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I am unable to run tests in Chrome and Firefox via UFt.I read over internet and found that we need to install patches for doing the same.Where can I download these Patches required and how do I need to install or configure them?

Comment: Which Version of UFT you are using ? You don't need any patches for 14.

Answer (score 1):

In order to run tests on Chrome and Firefox browsers, you need to enable HP Functional Testing Agent extension on both the browsers.

Please check the following links:

> [**Enable the HP Functional Testing Agent Chrome extension**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.54/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Chrome_Extension_Setup.htm)
>
> [**Enable the Functional Testing Agent for Mozilla Firefox**](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.54/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Firefox_Extension_Setup.htm)

You also want to consider [***Set up multiple browser testing***](http://uft-help.saas.hpe.com/en/12.54/UFT_Help/Content/Addins_Guide/Wrk_Multi_Browsers_How2.htm)

Given links are for UFT 12.54. If you are using different version of UFT than select the appropriate version from dropdown on these pages.